# How do I check for a CC address as well as my current check for the TO address?

Tags: vba, outlook

I currently use the following to check for the TO address in an Outlook VBA program ...

```
If MyEMail.Recipients.Item(1).Address = "MyAddress@gmail.com"
```

How do I check for the same address in the CC field, please ?

I wrote this ages ago, and I generally research how to do things when I do them and then forget how and why I did them :-) !!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you hardcoding the index (1)? Loop through all recipients in the `MyEMail.Recipients` collection and for each recipient, check the `Recipiet.Type` property (can be `olTo`, `olCC`, `olBCC`).

```
for each recip in MyEMail.Recipients
  if (recip.Address = "MyAddress@gmail.com") Then
    if recip.Type = olTo Then 
      MsgBox "Sent to a To recipient"
    else if recip.Type = olCC Then 
      MsgBox "Sent to a CC recipient"
    end if
  End If 
next
```

Comment: There is no need to loop, these E:Mails only ever come from one person, but I have different E:Mail addresses for different things and he has the habit of sending to one address and CCing the other, and if he puts the important address in the CC then my check fails !!

Comment: If I enter "If MyEMail.Recipients." I don't get an option of Type, I just get Add, Application, Class, Count, Item, Parent, Remove, ResolveAll & Session ...

Comment: If there are multiple addresses (To and CC), there is no guarantee the To address will be first. Again, do loop through all recipients.

Comment: See the modified answer above for an example

Comment: Sorry, a bit out of touch and a few beers down right now ... I have to Declare all my variables ... what do I declare recip as ?!?

Comment: Outlook.Recipient? Take at look various Outlook objects with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click Item button.